# get group text value of dropdown jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to retrieve group text of my drop down in variable and then assign to a textbox named "txtRegion"

```
<select id="cmbCity" name="cmbCity" multiple="multiple">
      <option group='Andaman & Nicobar Islands|NORTH' value='1' >Port Blair</option>
</select>
```

I have tried following code but doesnt seem to be work

```
$("#cmbCity").change(function() {
    var n = $("#cmbCity").attr('group').text();
    alert(n);
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#cmbCity").change(function() {
    var n = $("#cmbCity option").attr('group');
    alert(n);
});
```

Comment: This code doesn't check which values are selected it simply adds all group attributes to the variable!

Answer (score 2):

Here is working code

/jquery

```
$(function(){

$("#cmbCity").change(function() {
    var n = $("#cmbCity option:selected").attr('group');
    alert(n);
});
})
```

//HTML

```
<select id="cmbCity" name="cmbCity" >
<option>select</option>

      <option group='Andaman & Nicobar Islands|NORTH' value='1' >Port Blair</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give correct selector path.Check this...
          http://jsfiddle.net/Mprks/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cmbCity").click(function(event) {

    var n = $("#cmbCity :selected").attr('group');
    alert(n);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mprks/1/